# Detecting a single-character XOR cipher

Tags: python, python-3.x

> One of the 60-character strings in [this file](http://cryptopals.com/static/challenge-data/4.txt) has been encrypted by single-character XOR.
>
> Find it.
>
> (Your code from [#3](http://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/3) should help.)

The challenge is to find which line of a file is XOR encrypted and what is gibberish. There is one line that is encrypted. Each line should be 60 characters (except I found one 58 character line).

For some reason, I am reading 61 characters on each line with 59 on the 58 character line and 60 only the last line. Why is this? I thought it was the new line character, but when I used `line[0:-1]` I had no success decrypting.

Here is my python code:

```
import binascii

def XORBreak(h):
    en = binascii.unhexlify(h)
    for key in range(256):
        de = ''.join(chr(b ^ key) for b in en)
        if de.isprintable():
            print(de)

with open("TestFile_Challenge04_CSIS463.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        XORBreak(line)
```

Comment: `line` contains newline. do `line.rstrip("\n")` to remove linefeed.

Comment: Oh true. Sorry. I posted the links @AnttiHaapala

Comment: Thank you @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: `isprintable()` is just too wide. But restricting to 32 => 128 doesn't give any valid string.

Comment: As in, isprintable() could be cutting out the solution? @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: don't think so. but I cannot find a problem in your code, and cannot find the string either. I could find the "Cooking MC's like a pound of bacon" with the same code. So it's strange.

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem. Challenge three worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should strip the whitespace (newlines and such) using `.strip`, e.g.:

```
for line in file
    xor_decrypt(line.strip())
```

instead of blindly removing the last character of a line.

---

Now, your code almost works, but it fails to find the correct string for a reason: `'\n'` is *not* printable:

```
>>> '\n'.isprintable()
False
```

Thus, `isprintable` on *any* string that contains a newline will return `False`.

You could instead use something like `any(c.isprintable() or c == '\n' for c in de)`.

Comment: I think that spaces are supposed to be included. They were in the last challenge.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but 'XORBreak(line.rstrip("\n"))' take out the new line character, not a arbitrary last character.